# Can root reliably determine the per-mount ("bind mount") flags e.g. for a FUSE filesystem?

Tags: linux, mount, fuse

FUSE filesystems mounted by a non-root user, cannot be accessed by root (unless `allow_other` is used on the mount).

As root, I want to query the per-mount flags such as `nosuid`, so that I can use `mount()` with `MS_REMOUNT|MS_BIND|...` to add the per-mount `MS_RDONLY` flag.  I have been successful on most filesystems using `statvfs()` to query the existing mount flags.  But is there a way to implement this that handles cases like FUSE (and NFS with root_squash)?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: ...a question about the Linux API that I needed to answer to in order to write a patch to C code in *systemd* is not about programming or development? I'm very happy on U&L if the Q needs to be moved, but I don't understand why.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  `statvfs()` works for this case also.  At the same time, it avoids blocking on the FUSE filesystem.

```
$ mkdir mnt
$ bindfs --no-allow-other mnt mnt
$ stat -f mnt
  File: "mnt"
    ID: 0        Namelen: 255     Type: fuseblk
Block size: 4096       Fundamental block size: 4096
Blocks: Total: 78150265   Free: 8223357    Available: 4722313
Inodes: Total: 19857408   Free: 18558102

$ strace stat -f mnt
...
statfs("mnt", {f_type=FUSE_SUPER_MAGIC, f_bsize=0, f_blocks=0, f_bfree=0, f_bavail=0, f_files=0, f_ffree=0, f_fsid={val=[0, 0]}, f_namelen=0, f_frsize=0, f_flags=ST_VALID|ST_NOSUID|ST_NODEV|ST_RELATIME}) = 0
...

  File: "mnt"
    ID: 0        Namelen: 0       Type: fuseblk
Block size: 0          Fundamental block size: 0
Blocks: Total: 0          Free: 0          Available: 0
Inodes: Total: 0          Free: 0
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

`statvfs()` is explicitly documented as not requiring access to the target directory, only the parents.

> EACCES (statvfs())  Search  permission is denied for a component of the
>                 path **prefix** of path.  (See also path_resolution(7).)

Unfortunately your process of re-mounting does have a race condition, that cannot be fixed if you cannot open the target directory.  Note `O_PATH` lets you open directories without requiring any permission on the directory itself.  (`O_PATH` fds can then be addressed as a path using `/proc/self/fd/%d`, including by `mount()`).